# I have two emacs buffers in a frame: A.cc | B.cc

Tags: emacs, buffer, frame

I have two emacs buffers in a frame: A.cc | B.cc

So assume I have focus on B.cc. I want to fast copy B.cc to the left window by one stroke (like some hotkeys).
the final state is B.cc | B.cc. Currently, I can only use C-x b and type in a few chars of the buffer name. this is very slow.

NOTE: this should not be another opened replica buffer(e.g., B.cc[replicated], you know what i mean if you are a emacs user) but exact the same buffer, just show in two different windows

Comment: The title "I have two emacs buffers in a frame: A.cc | B.cc" is neither a problem, nor remotely indicative of what the problem is.

Comment: How about a title such as?:  *Switch to current buffer in other window.*  Or?:  *Display current buffer in other window.*

Comment: I would interprete a 'replica buffer' as `clone-indirect-buffer`. You can connect this to `other-window` with `clone-indirect-buffer-other-window` which is bound to `C-x 4 c` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Select the other window:

```
(switch-to-buffer-other-window (current-buffer))
```

Do *not* select the other window:

```
(display-buffer (current-buffer) t)
```

Select the other window.:

```
(pop-to-buffer (current-buffer) 'other-window)
```

---

Here is an example of a global keyboard shortcut using the F5 key -- insert whatever function you want instead of `...`:

```
(global-set-key [f5] (lambda ()
  (interactive)
    ... ))
```